# react router How to organize dynamic router for 2 level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How to organize dynamic router for 2 level 
I have structure like this

```
<Router history={browserHistory}  >
<Route path='/' component={App} data={DISTRICT}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
         <Route path='/:district' component={District}/>
            <Route path='/:district/:directory' component={Directory}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
</Router>
```

for district all work good
but doesnt work for directory
How to render component of directory?

App.js

```
 render() {        
            return (
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    { this.renderChildren() } 
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest your `directory` route in `district` route.

You need to refactor your `routes` as

```
<Router history={browserHistory}  >
  <Route path='/' component={App} data={DISTRICT}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path=':district' component={District}>
      <Route path=':directory' component={Directory}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
</Router>
```

Comment: I receive the same result , maybe it because
I am adding url params using of click
like this  browserHistory.push( this.slug) ?

Comment: Now try removing `/` before `params` as in answer

Comment: can you post your `components`? I mean implementation of `containers`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem
I added slug use `browserHistory.push( this.slug)`
but I needed adding full pathname like this

```
browserHistory.push( location.pathname + this.slug )
```

I now have the following   structure of routes

```
<Router history={browserHistory}  >
<Route path='/' component={App} data={DISTRICT}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
         <Route path=':district' component={District}/>
            <Route path=':district/:directory' component={Directory}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
</Router>
```